# Qt Qml TextField onEditingFinished not called when clicking on a MenuItem

Tags: qt, events, qml

In my Qml example I have a TextField where the user can input a value.
When the user clicks on "save" in the menu I want to have the editing automatically finished. I would have expected this would already happen, since I thought clicking the MenuBar would move the focus away, but apparently this is not the case.

How would you handle something like that? In the full application I have several fields which are connected to a model so I don't want to manually read out each value in the save handler.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400; height: 200

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "&Document"
            MenuItem {
                text: "&Save"
                onTriggered: console.log("save clicked")
            }
        }
    }

    TextField {
        onEditingFinished: console.log("editing finished")
    }

}
```

Expected output:

```
editing finished
save clicked
```

Actual output

```
save clicked
```

Comment: Odd – can confirm on OSX. I didn't see a bug open for that – why not file one. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46908?jql=text%20~%20%22TextField%20onEditingFinished%22

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if it really is a bug or a design decision. I asked the same question for vanilla Qt two years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082582/qt4-no-focus-loss-on-clicking-menubar at that time the solution was to install a custom EventFilter which calls clearFocus on a button press on the menubar.